# eZ Publish Site Package Error

Tags: content-management-system, ezpublish

I am installing ez publish(CMS) in my xampp...
however in this section of installation

**SITE PACKAGE**
[image]

I can't proceed even though I can click next.. I bet the site package is mandatory... I need your help guys... btw, I am installing 2013.5 version

here's the error

> Error
>   Invalid package
>   Remote repository URL: http://packages.ez.no/ezpublish/5.0/5.0.0/

I've tried uploading the `ezwebin_site.ezpkg` in the remote repository still I can't proceed... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Site Package selection step within the Setup Wizard is more or less required (you must select one package using the ratio buttons) to complete a proper eZ Publish installation first time.

Notice the 'Help' sidebar content, "The type of site will choose some basic settings for toolbars, menus, color and functionality. It is possible to change these settings at a later time.".

This is to remind new users that you first use the setup wizard for your first time installation of eZ Publish and then you can re-configure eZ Publish settings, design, extensions, etc manually as much as you desire / require. You can customize almost any part of eZ Publish, once you have it installed and setup properly.

It is recommended for new users to install the 'Website Interface' (with content) package for your first installation. Again you can change all it all after you have completed the default installation and have a working default installation.

More experienced developers may choose to use the 'Plain site' package (with no content, and significantly less default functionality and helpful tools) but this option often causes extreme confusion to new users / developers (who need the tools provided in the 'Website Interface' package to get started using eZ Publish quickly) as it omits expected content classes, default content use case examples, roles / policies, default settings use case examples, ezwebin design extension and much more. As such any package choice other than 'Website Interface' (with the version of eZ Publish you are using) is very strongly discouraged.

Advanced Developers with an already setup installation can create their own site packages to reuse in the future to simplify configuration of a default installation.

Resolution Edit: During an extensive stackoverflow and irc chat it was determined that the user asking the question lacked the WAMP server (PHP modules) support required by eZ Publish 5.x which is why the user was having installation setup problems. Specifically the user was missing the required php curl module which is used / required by the setup wizard to download site packages. The user was strongly recommended to replace Xampp (on win32) with Bitnami (for eZ) which provides for all the requirements of eZ Publish 5.x by default and has already been heavily tested and customized for use with eZ Publish 5.x. Also the user was using an older version of eZ Publish 5.x (2013.5 community build) which only supports PHP 5.3 and the user's Xampp PHP version was PHP 5.6.8 which requires at the very least eZ Publish 5.x (2014.11 community build).

Comment: so how can I install ezpublish without uploading sitepackage...?

Comment: I've also tried uploading the remote repository for the site package.. still got an error..

Comment: Your not making much sense when you ask, "I install ezpublish without uploading sitepackage". You don't upload site packages, you download them into the eZ Publish installation your running the Setup Wizard on. Your also not making much sense when you say, "... uploading the remote repository for the site package" as that also is not something that  is normally done. I think you should follow my answer as it is correct. If your still having problems please describe them much more clearly with more specific detail.

Comment: Hello Heath, Is it possible to install ez publish without it's site package?. as you can see it is not imported yet... can you guide me throughout the stages of installation?

Comment: No, you must select a site package to install eZ

Comment: yeah, when I select one of those choices it prompt me some error `Error
Invalid package
Remote repository URL: http://packages.ez.no/ezpublish/5.0/5.0.0/` do you have any idea?

Comment: I can not find that string (or subset) within the eZ Publish source code (for this version). I hate to ask but it would help if you could post a url to a screenshot of the full screen containing the error (not cropped).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78672/discussion-between-heath-and-user3113490).

Comment: The author of this question cross-posted on http://share.ez.no/forums/install-configuration/create-site-problem